# Find length of connected cells of 1s

Tags: c, algorithm

I wrote code to find the length of connected cells of 1s. But it hits segfault. I did my best to debug but i don't get any clue. Greatly appreciate any inputs!

input 2d array:

```
11000
01100
00101
10001
01011
```

output: 5

I am simply trying to find max length from all 8 directions of a given cell. I repeat that for all cells in the 2d-array and find the max length of connected 1's. using the backtracking/recursion method.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_arr(int arr[5][5], int row, int col) {

    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < col; c++)
            printf("%d ", arr[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int find_conneted_len_dir(int arr[5][5], int max_row, int max_col, int org_r, int org_c) {
    int dir_r;
    int dir_c;
    int dir_max = 0;
    int cur_max = 0;
    //printf("dir %d, %d\n",org_r,org_c);
    if ((org_r < 0) || (org_r >= 5) || (org_c < 0) || (org_c >= 5))
        return 0;

    if (arr[org_r][org_c] == 0)
        return 0;

    for (dir_r = -1; dir_r <= 1; dir_r++) {
        for (dir_c = -1; dir_c <= 1; dir_c++) {
            if ((dir_r == 0) && (dir_c == 0))
                continue;

            if (((org_r + dir_r) < 0) || ((org_r + dir_r) >= 5) || ((org_c + dir_c) < 0) || ((org_c + dir_c) >= 5))
                continue;
            //printf("from %d - %d : \n", org_r + dir_r, org_c + dir_c);
            if (arr[org_r + dir_r][org_c + dir_c] == 1 ) {
                cur_max = 1 + find_conneted_len_dir(arr, max_row, max_col, org_r + dir_r, org_c + dir_c);
                //printf("-->cur_max = %d\n", cur_max);
                if (cur_max > dir_max)
                    dir_max = cur_max;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir_max;
}

int find_conneted_len(int arr[5][5], int row, int col) {
    int r, c;
    int max_row = row;
    int max_col = col;
    int max_len = 0;
    int len = 0;
    for (r = 0; r < max_row; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < max_col; c++) {
            //printf("from top %d - %d : ", r, c);
            if (arr[r][c] != 0) {
                len = find_conneted_len_dir(arr, max_row, max_col, r, c);
                //printf("top len = %d\n", len);
                if (len > max_len)
                    max_len = len;
            }
        }
    }

    return max_len;
}

int main() {
    int arr[5][5] = {
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            {1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
            {0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
    };
    int row = 5, col = 5;

    print_arr(arr, row, col);
    int max_len = find_conneted_len(arr, row, col);
    printf("max_len = %d\n", max_len);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault? Run your program in a debugger and it will tell you that instantly. That's the minimum amount of debug info you should post. Can also use the debugger to examine the indices and other variables to check which ones may be wrong and then can step thru the code to trace how they became wrong. That is, much more debugging can be done.

Comment: This question has nothing specific to C++. It should be tagged with `c` only.

Comment: removed c++ tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you keep revisiting back and forth the same neighboring cells. This leads to an infinite recursion, depleting the stack.

A solution is to mark the visited cells, by replacing their 1 with a 0.

There is also another issue in your code. There is no need to take maximums of separate counts made by recursive calls. No, these counts all belong to the same connected area, so they should accumulate. So just use one `count` variable, and not two.

Here is a proposed change for your function:

```
int find_conneted_len_dir(int arr[5][5], int max_row, int max_col, int org_r, int org_c) {
    int dir_r;
    int dir_c;
    int count = 1; // Use one counter only, and count the current cell

    if ((org_r < 0) || (org_r >= 5) || (org_c < 0) || (org_c >= 5))
        return 0;

    if (arr[org_r][org_c] == 0)
        return 0;

    arr[org_r][org_c] = 0; // clear it

    for (dir_r = -1; dir_r <= 1; dir_r++) {
        for (dir_c = -1; dir_c <= 1; dir_c++) {
            if ((dir_r == 0) && (dir_c == 0))
                continue;
            if (((org_r + dir_r) < 0) || ((org_r + dir_r) >= 5) || ((org_c + dir_c) < 0) || ((org_c + dir_c) >= 5))
                continue;
            if (arr[org_r + dir_r][org_c + dir_c] == 1 ) {
                count += find_conneted_len_dir(arr, max_row, max_col, org_r + dir_r, org_c + dir_c);
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks, @trincot. if we clear arr[org_r][org_c] = 0 then aren't we modifying the actual array? won't that create trouble for the next iteration? I ran your changes, it works but unable to understand it completely.

Comment: The point is that you don't want to count a 1 twice, **ever**, so when you count it, it is safe to set it to 0. Yes, this mutates your actual array, and at the very end, it will not have any 1 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns a stack overflow error (`3221225725`).
That means your program ran out of memory due to calling one recursive function too many times. It would likely never stop by itself.

`find_conneted_len_dir`  always evaluates `if (arr[org_r + dir_r][org_c + dir_c] == 1 )` to `true` at some point, no matter what input values are. This is causing it to repeat itself infinitely.